# Error - Type Error DeclartativeMeta object got multiple values for keyword argument 'owner_id'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

i have a question, ive been banging my head against my desk for too long so iam taking it to stackoverflow. hope you guys can help me! :)

although i know the Error is very specific, i cant seem to get my head arround it. Iam trying to create a relationship that goes as follows A User has One Account and One Account has many trades. Still iam getting the error back:

`TypeError: DeclarativeMeta object got multiple values for keyword argument 'owner_id'`

if someone could please explain this to me that would be great!

Iam working with Python, fastapi and sqlalchemy although, i do think that i made a mistake with sqlalchemy

My models.py

```
# User model
class User(_database.Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = _sql.Column(_sql.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    email = _sql.Column(_sql.String, unique=True, index=True)
    hashed_password = _sql.Column(_sql.String)
    date_created = _sql.Column(_sql.DateTime, default=_dt.datetime.utcnow)

    accounts = _orm.relationship("Account", back_populates="owner")
    trades = _orm.relationship("Trade", back_populates="trades")

    # Function om te checken of het verzonden password matched met het hashed passowrd met bcrypt
    def verify_password(self, password: str):
        return _hash.bcrypt.verify(password, self.hashed_password)


# Account model
class Account(_database.Base):
    __tablename__ = "accounts"
    id = _sql.Column(_sql.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    owner_id = _sql.Column(_sql.Integer, _sql.ForeignKey("users.id"))
    first_name = _sql.Column(_sql.String, index=True)
    last_name = _sql.Column(_sql.String, index=True)
    role = _sql.Column(_sql.String, index=True)
    note = _sql.Column(_sql.String, default="")
    date_created = _sql.Column(_sql.DateTime, default=_dt.datetime.utcnow)
    date_last_updated = _sql.Column(_sql.DateTime, default=_dt.datetime.utcnow)

    owner = _orm.relationship("User", back_populates="accounts")


# Trade Model
class Trade(_database.Base):
    __tablename__ = "trades"
    id = _sql.Column(_sql.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    owner_id = _sql.Column(
        _sql.Integer, _sql.ForeignKey("users.id")
    )  # Krijgt een FK mee zodat een trade bij User kan komen
    trade_id = _sql.Column(
        _sql.Integer, index=True
    )  # Trades die gemaakt zijn hebben een uniek id vanuit exchange
    ticker = _sql.Column(
        _sql.String, index=True
    )  # Welke ticket is de trade gemaakt bv BTC/USDT, DOGE/USDT, etc.
    exchange = _sql.Column(
        _sql.String, index=True
    )  # Op welke exchange is de trade gemaakt
    date_created = _sql.Column(_sql.DateTime, default=_dt.datetime.utcnow)
    trade_note = _sql.Column(
        _sql.String, default=""
    )  # kunnen mensen toevoegen waarom ze een trade zijn ingestrap (Soort logboek)

    trades = _orm.relationship("User", back_populates="trades")
```

My services.py (The function that throws the error is create_trade(), it is the last one)

```
async def create_user(user: _schemas.UserCreate, db: _orm.Session):
    user_obj = _models.User(
        email=user.email, hashed_password=_hash.bcrypt.hash(user.hashed_password)
    )
    db.add(user_obj)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(user_obj)
    return user_obj


async def authenticate_user(email: str, password: str, db: _orm.Session):
    user = await get_user_by_email(db=db, email=email)

    if not user:
        return False

    if not user.verify_password(password):
        return False

    return user


async def create_token(user: _models.User):
    user_obj = _schemas.User.from_orm(user)

    token = _jwt.encode(user_obj.dict(), JWT_SECRET)

    return dict(access_token=token, token_type="bearer")


async def get_current_user(
    db: _orm.Session = _fastapi.Depends(get_db),
    token: str = _fastapi.Depends(oauth2schema),
):
    try:
        payload = _jwt.decode(token, JWT_SECRET, algorithms=["HS256"])
        user = db.query(_models.User).get(payload["id"])
    except:
        raise _fastapi.HTTPException(
            status_code=401, detail="Invalid Email or Password"
        )

    return _schemas.User.from_orm(user)


async def create_trade(
    user: _schemas.User, db: _orm.Session, trade: _schemas.TradeCreate
):
    # **trade.dict() 'unpacked' als het waren de Trade model dus je kan zegegen
    # zelfde als het zeggen trade.owner_id = owner_id, trade.ticker = ticker, etc.

    trade = _models.Trade(**trade.dict(), owner_id=user.id)
    db.add(trade)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(trade)

    print(f"{user.id} ================")

    return _schemas.Trade.from_orm(trade)
```

And last but not least my main.py

```
@app.post("/api/users")
async def create_user(
    user: _schemas.UserCreate, db: _orm.Session = _fastapi.Depends(_services.get_db)
):
    db_user = await _services.get_user_by_email(user.email, db)
    if db_user:
        raise _fastapi.HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Email already exists")

    await _services.create_user(user, db)

    return await _services.create_token(user)


# Token om toegang te krijgen tot authenticated gedeelte


@app.post("/api/token")
async def generate_token(
    form_data: _security.OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = _fastapi.Depends(),
    db: _orm.Session = _fastapi.Depends(_services.get_db),
):
    # gebruikt email
    user = await _services.authenticate_user(form_data.username, form_data.password, db)

    if not user:
        raise _fastapi.HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Invalid Credentials")

    return await _services.create_token(user)


# @param me - is als in de authenticated user, hier staat me dus voor
@app.get("/api/users/me", response_model=_schemas.User)
async def get_user(user: _schemas.User = _fastapi.Depends(_services.get_current_user)):
    return user


@app.post("/api/trades", response_model=_schemas.Trade)
async def create_trade(
    trade: _schemas.TradeCreate,
    user: _schemas.User = _fastapi.Depends(_services.get_current_user),
    db: _orm.Session = _fastapi.Depends(_services.get_db),
):
    return await _services.create_trade(user=user, db=db, trade=trade)
```

schema.py

```
class AccountCreate(_AccountBase):
    pass


class Account(_AccountBase):
    id: int
    owner_id: int
    date_created: _dt.datetime
    date_late_updated: _dt.datetime

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class _TradeBase(_pydantic.BaseModel):
    id: int
    owner_id: int
    trade_id: int
    ticker: str
    exchange: str
    date_created: _dt.datetime
    trade_note: str


# De twee functies hieronder vooralsnog (redundant wordt niks mee gedaan)
class Trade(_TradeBase):
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

    pass


class TradeCreate(_TradeBase):
    pass
```

All tips and tricks are welcome! Thank you!

Comment: Please, add your TradeCreate schema code.

Comment: Whoops wasnt my brightest move there! Added it! @kosciej16

Comment: You added models.py twice now and there is still no TradeCreate ;/

Comment: Correction ahah... THIS wasnt my brightest moment. Thanks for the patience :8 @kosciej16

Comment: You should use to that, most of our programming trials aren't the brightest ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what I thought, look here:

```
trade = _models.Trade(**trade.dict(), owner_id=user.id)
```

Notice that trade has already `owner_id` field. That mean you try to pass it twice. You must think do you need `owner_id` in trade at all. If so, you need to remove one `owner_id` from there:

```
trade = _models.Trade(**trade.dict())
```

or with [exclude](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#advanced-include-and-exclude)

```
trade = _models.Trade(**trade.dict(exclude={"owner_id"}), owner_id=user.id)
```

Comment: Ahh!!! Thank you so much for explaining! I do think i would like to have the owner_id since i want to be able to find the trades for a specific user (and later on display them to the user). Would this be a good solution or would you do it another way? again thanks for helping, it works like a charm!

Comment: I meant you could remove `owner_id` from TradeCreate schema as you don't use it anyway. So in your specific case, move `owner_id` from `_TradeBase` to `Trade`

Comment: Actually the same could apply to id - how is it possible you know id before you insert it into database? You can of course track of ids in frontend, but it's much more effective to let db assign id with some sequence (or uuid) and return it in response if needed. + trade_id/id seems redundant at first sight